# C# Keypress hook - backspace remove only one last char

Tags: c#, hook, backspace

When I want to delete the last few characters and press the backspace (press, press, press) everything works fine, but if I press the backspace button once and hold it for a longer time, it removes only the last character and not a few. How to improve it?

```
public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyValue >= 65 && e.KeyValue <= 90) || (e.KeyValue >= 96 && e.KeyValue <= 105))
    {
        switch (e.KeyValue)
        {
            case (96): { keysPressed += "0"; } break;
            case (97): { keysPressed += "1"; } break;
            case (98): { keysPressed += "2"; } break;
            case (99): { keysPressed += "3"; } break;
            case (100): { keysPressed += "4"; } break;
            case (101): { keysPressed += "5"; } break;
            case (102): { keysPressed += "6"; } break;
            case (103): { keysPressed += "7"; } break;
            case (104): { keysPressed += "8"; } break;
            case (105): { keysPressed += "9"; } break;
            default:
                { keysPressed += ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString(); }
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyValue == 8)
    {
        if (keysPressed.Length > 1)
        {
            keysPressed = keysPressed.Remove(keysPressed.Length - 1);
            // what to do so that the backspace removes more characters on one long press.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Start a `Timer` in _keydown_ and stop it in _keyup_. In `Timer.Tick` do your char adding/deleting.

Comment: Your code works as-is; holding backspace removes multiple characters from `keysPressed`. Do you have any other functions or events that change the value of `keysPressed`?

Comment: @schlonzo OP's goal is to detect multiple `KeyDown` events when a key is held. How would detecting `KeyUp` achieve that? And if the goal of using a `Timer` were to detect a full key press, why not just use the `KeyPress` event?

Comment: @eclecticist As long as there is no key up, he knows that the key still is pressed and can do the adding/deleteing repeatedly in a timer.tick. Because KeyDown only is fired once. So this is not enough for detecting a holded down key...

Comment: The `KeyDown` event fires multiple times for me when a key is held. I tested a textbox in a WinForms app.